# Filtras estructuras o arreglos en c++

Tags: c++, array, c, estructuras

Estoy intentando imprimir en consola una lista de grupos y sus profesores asignados en grupos ya definidos con este script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int total_profesores = 2;
char grupos[20] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T'};

struct datosProfesores {
    string nombre;
    char grupo;
}profesor[total_profesores];
    
for(int i = 0; i < total_profesores; i++){
    cout << "ingresa nombre del maestro" << ": ";
    cin >> profesor[i].nombre;
    
    cout << "ingresa el grupo del maestro [" << profesor[i].nombre << "] (A - T): ";
    cin >> profesor[i].grupo;
    
    cout << endl << endl;
}

//Es aquí donde tengo el problema
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    if(profesor[i].grupo == grupos[i]){
        cout << "Profesor " << profesor[i].nombre << " asignado" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Sin profesor asignado" << endl;
    }
}   

return 0;
```

}

Soy bastante nuevo en c y quisiera mostrar los grupos con sus respectivos maestros pero no encuentro la forma de manejar los arreglos, alguna recomendación?

Comment: He leído tu pregunta y no entiendo qué quieres hacer. He compilado y ejecutado tu código y sigue sin verle la funcionalidad. Estás ingresando 2 nombres de los profesores y le asocias una letra respecto a un grupo concreto. Date cuenta que el tamaño de tu `struct` es de 2, por lo que vas a tener únicamente 2 profesores, pero luego en el bucle `for` que dices que no te funciona estás yendo hasta `profesor[i]`, **¡ donde `i` puede valer hasta 19 !** Debes emplear otra variable de control para el array de estructuras `profesor`, y hacer la comparación como `profesor[j].grupo == grupos[i]`

Comment: Date cuenta que esa variable `j` que te permitirá controlar las estructuras irá desde 0 hasta `total_profesores`, por lo que también te voy adelantando que tendrás que implementar un `for` del tipo `for ( int j=0 ; j<total_profesores ; j++) { ..... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás describiendo una casuística para la que se diseñaron los [contenedores asociativos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers). En tu caso, parece que la mejor elección es un mapa cuya clave sea el grupo y cuyo valor sea una lista de nombres en dicho grupo:

```
using datosProfesores = std::map<char, std::list<std::string>>;
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
datosProfesores profesores;

for (int indice = 0; indice != total_profesores; ++indice) {
    cout << "ingresa nombre del maestro: ";
    string nombre;
    cin >> nombre;
    
    cout << "ingresa el grupo del maestro [" << nombre << "] (A - T): ";
    char grupo;
    cin >> grupo;
    
    profesores[grupo].push_back(nombre);
}
```

Después podrás mostrar los datos así:

```
for (const auto &[grupo, lista] : profesores)
{
    cout << "Grupo " << grupo << ":\n\t"
    for (const auto &profesor : lista)
        cout << profesor << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJNb9swDIbP5q/gUmCJkWYYdtjBdgykDdBrD7s1QcHISqrNlgxJHgYU/evzKMtJvHUn8/PhS8qibVeiJn3q@xulRd1VEouG2hKubq2cn/rOW6VP04gyHJPUlACd4xxW5I17tOYonbHS4Rqdr7KMwYV4IXsb3QAuBmtEljmA0h4bUnqRwiskEaepka4lIUMf1yT/8tuLmUMijHZe/motUucNeuOpfm6nYr4GxtFYXIRpSleK0Wv8nJ/tD@t3bTkulzGbIgvjKZ3HosAZC@Q0oTbNwUqsZM36JW9kMpyxnCQuN@ZDQCiNZXkJ/A/GkJPtWjPF4dMs1IxzQvUeFxtc4bd0nBRuG/smY0afA9dlnobg/lPbuZfnA4kfi0hNue/tfJvhjvGGH2PDLYYnoz1mk4unkPx1j4dB9yA1rhCC2U7v/KDxHfpMYuhAZ96VdkmyPcd5Phk03@n5KNdK31nN7wdvfb@pD2QNbODO2O8Ed3BPtjYO7mFLP1UFW9iqigR/uVJaH0p/i2NNJ9ev@P9ai@XyC/0B)</kbd>.